# Ajuda com proteção

Tags: php, mysql

Olá estou desenvolvendo um sistema de comentários coisa simples, estou usando php com ajax, e armazenando em um banco de dados MySQL, a minha dúvida é a seguinte,

entrada

```
$MENSAGEM = filter_var($text, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
```

como posso evitar dos comentários deste tipo.

```
pppppp........ ou udaisoduasiudaosidua....   repetindo...
```

que acaba quebrando todo o site?

sei que da pra fazer isso ajustando com css, mais eu queria barrar essa postagem usando o php.

o meu sistema já conta com login, só quem pode fazer postagem é usuários!

Comment: poderia postar seu código e dar mais detalhes da sua dúvida? A ideia seria criar uma "black list" de comentários? Poderia explicar melhor o "quebrando todo o site"?

Comment: coisa simples, estou usando php com ajax, e armazenando em um banco de dados MySQL.

Comment: sim, isso eu entendi. Mas se o campo for aberto, não tem como prever o que o usuário vai digitar. Uma letra diferente da sua regra, já vai furar. O que você pode fazer é enviar esse comentário para aprovação de um moderador antes da publicação. Ou também criar uma "blacklist" contendo as palavras de "spam" mais utilizadas e fazer um tratamento antes da postagem, mas mesmo assim a chance de passar é grande.

Comment: O problema foi resolvido, usando CSS e Limitando os caracteres e moderação!

Comment: vou fazer isso, obrigado a todos!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$str = "sssrrrry";

$v = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "y", "z");


for($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++){

$quant = substr_count($str, $v[$i]);

$cont[] = $quant;

}

rsort($cont);

if($cont[0] > 1){

echo "Houve ". $cont[0] ." duplicações de somente 1 caractere na string";

}



?>
```

referência: https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/473081-remover-caracteres-repetidos/
por : Daniel_Moraes

Comment: E ainda da pra colocar um str_replace() pra corrigir o erro, evitando do usuário ficar procurando onde errou

Comment: o problema é que se o usuário postar letras aleatória passa isso ai, e o resultado é o mesmo. ex: udaisoduasiudaosiduaiosa .....

Comment: @CamilaF moça, que tipo de comentário você não pode colocar um haushudahushduahsud KKKKKKKKK, acho melhor melhorar a sua estrutura no seu site kkk

Comment: então faça restrições de frases, palavras grandes etc... e como é comum a utilização de "kkkk" ou risadas que envolve "h" apenas faça a liberação dessas duas letras para palavras grandes, cabe a você como programadora as restrições de seu sistema.

Comment: Tudo bem! obrigado.